# Exact alignment of caption beside figure

Tags: captions, vertical-alignment

I want to typeset some captions beside figures and in doing so observed some weird behaviour (at least for me).
I use two minipages and for a minimal example everything aligns neatly at the baseline (figure 1).
However, if I add a `\label` right after the caption, the reference point now seems to be at the very bottom (figure 2).
The same happens rather surprisingly if I add the `color` package. Only this time, the alignment is "wrong" even without a label.

Could someone enlighten me on how the reference point is affected by `\label` and what the `color` package has got to do with that?

[image]

```
%!TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass[draft]{article}

\usepackage{lua-visual-debug}
\usepackage[position=bottom,font=footnotesize]{caption}
% \usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.6\linewidth}
    \centering
    \rule{0.8\linewidth}{60pt}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.4\linewidth}
    \caption{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.6\linewidth}
    \centering
    \rule{0.8\linewidth}{60pt}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.4\linewidth}
    \caption{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}
    \label{fig:fox}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alas, @egreg’s explanation, although captivating, is incorrect.
(But I too was deceived at first, since I upvoted it! :-)
Notwithstanding the fallacious diagnosis, however, the cure he suggests
is equally efficacious, so I wouldn’t bother to write this answer,
if it weren’t for a detail that 
might actually confuse the casual reader: @egreg’s answer implies that a 
`\label` command occurring as the last thing in a vertical box always 
smashes the depth of that box, but this is not at all the case.

The correct explanation, however, is a pretty long story, so I must ask 
you to be patient.  Let us begin by recapping the rules by 
which TeX computes the depth of a vertical box it is constructing with 
`\vbox` (the rules for `\vtop` and `\vcenter` are related to these, but 
different), which are detailed in *The TeXbook* on pages 80 (bottom) and 
81 (top).  The general rule is quite simple and natural: the depth of the 
constructed `\vbox` is the depth of the bottommost box inside it.  This 
rule has *only* three exceptions:

1. when the constructed box contains no boxes,
   in which case its depth is zero (obvious);
2. when the last box inside the `\vbox` has glue, or kerning,
   somewhere below it, in which case the “outer” depth is zero
   too (seems reasonable);
3. when the user has set an explicit threshold for the depth,
   by setting the `\boxmaxdepth` parameter, in which case the
   threshold is honored (again, obvious).

In particular, “whatsit” nodes are “transparent” to the depth of the 
bottommost box, as we’ll show below with a simple experiment.

Now, if a `\caption` command comes last in a `\vbox` that is being
constructed, in normal circumstances exception 2, above, *is* applied to
the line (or to the last one of the lines) it typesets, because that line
*does* have glue below itself, namely, the `\belowcaptionskip` glue (see,
for instance, the definition of `\@makecaption` in `classes.pdf`, in
particular code line 1122).  This means that, if `\belowcaptionskip`
retains its default value of `0pt`, in normal circumstances the caption
will *not* have its baseline aligned with the baseline of an enclosing box,
but rather its outer, “off-the-depth” contour, as in the second of the OP’s
examples (yes, exception 2 applies also if the amount of glue is zero).  So
the question to ask is, rather, “Why doesn’t this happen in the first
example?”

The point is, here, that in both cases the caption is wrapped in a 
`minipage` environment, and the code that gets executed when this 
environment ends (contained in the macro `\endminipage`, see its 
definition in `latex.ltx`), among other things issues—aha!—an `\unskip`;
the latter is a TeX primitive command that *removes* the last glue node 
from the current list.  Thus, the `\unskip` removes the glue coming from 
`\belowcaptionskip`, so that exception 2 no longer applies, and the depth 
of the last line makes it into the level of the enclosing box.

“OK—you ask—but then, why doesn’t this happen in the second example too?”
The point, now, is that the `\unskip` command can remove the last glue node
*only if it is still the very last node in the current list*.  Here
@egreg’s original explanation steps in: if a `\label` command follows
`\caption`, then it appends (notice: *after* `\caption` has completed, so
*below* the `\belowcaptionskip` glue!)  a “whatsit” node (that will show up
in diagnostic tracings as a `\write` node); the `\unskip` will then find
this “whatsit”, *not* the glue, and will therefore have no effect at all.
Thus, the glue node from `\belowcaptionskip` will survive, making exception
2 apply.  In other words, the presence of the `\label` command does not directly make any of above exceptions apply, it is only relevant in that it prevents `\upskip` from doing its job.

Most of the claims set forth above can be proved if you experiment
with the following code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% \setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{\bigskipamount}

% \makeatletter
% 
% \def\endminipage{%
%     \par
% %     \unskip
%     \ifvoid\@mpfootins\else
%       \vskip\skip\@mpfootins
%       \normalcolor
%       \footnoterule
%       \unvbox\@mpfootins
%     \fi
%     \@minipagefalse   %% added 24 May 89
%   \color@endgroup
%   \egroup
%   \expandafter\@iiiparbox\@mpargs{\unvbox\@tempboxa}}
% 
% \makeatother

\showboxbreadth = 1000
\showboxdepth = 10
% \tracingoutput = 1



\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.6\linewidth}
    \centering
    \rule{0.99\linewidth}{60pt}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.4\linewidth}
    \caption{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.6\linewidth}
    \centering
    \rule{0.99\linewidth}{60pt}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.4\linewidth}
    \caption{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}
    \label{fig:fox}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

% \showlists

\setbox0 = \vbox{
    \hsize = 10cm
    \prevdepth = 2pt % not actually important
    The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.\par
    \label{box}
}

The depth of \verb|\box0| is \the\dp0.

% \showbox0

\unvbox0

\end{document}
```

and uncomment its various portions to try different alternatives.  For 
example, uncommenting

```
% \setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{\bigskipamount}
```

will show you that `\belowcaptionskip` survives in the second example, 
but not in the first.  Uncommenting

```
% \makeatletter
% 
% \def\endminipage{%
%     \par
% %     \unskip
%     \ifvoid\@mpfootins\else
%       \vskip\skip\@mpfootins
%       \normalcolor
%       \footnoterule
%       \unvbox\@mpfootins
%     \fi
%     \@minipagefalse   %% added 24 May 89
%   \color@endgroup
%   \egroup
%   \expandafter\@iiiparbox\@mpargs{\unvbox\@tempboxa}}
% 
% \makeatother
```

will prove that the `\unskip` at the end of the `minipage` environment is
indeed the culprit for the glue removal (of course, one could also use the
`\patchcmd` utility from the `etoolbox` package, here).  Moreover,
uncommenting

```
% \showlists
```

will include an enlightening diagostic listing in your transcript file
(if you know how to read it); and uncommenting

```
% \showbox0
```

will produce a similar listing which proves that the `\write` node produced 
by the `\label` command is indeed the last node inside `\box0` (but, 
notwithstanding this, the depth of the inner box survives at the outer 
level, as the typeset output shows).

On the other hand, uncommenting

```
% \tracingoutput = 1
```

serves no purpose in our case, since all `figure`s have got `[h]` as their 
position specifier (and the `h` happens to be honored by LaTeX!).

I am pretty tired now, so I will leave the explanation concerning the
`color` package “as an exercise” (*hint:* remove the `lua-visual-debug` 
package and look closely… ;-) .

I did say that this was a pretty long story, but the O.P. asked for 
“enligthening”, and this is what I have tried to provide…

---

### Addition: Answer to the “exercise”

As it is well known, the original TeX did not deal with color at all; in
order to implement it, the `color` package (on which all other packages
that provide color facilities are based) have recourse as well to “whatsit”
nodes included at appropriate places in the lists being constructed.  In
particular, in order to properly restore, at the end of a box, the color
settings that were in force outside it, a special mechanism is used whereby
a certain kind of node, containing the appropriate instructions for the
rendering device, is appendd *after* the box in question.  The exact nature
of this node, and how it is reported in diagnostic listings, depends on the
typesetting engine being used; for instance, it is reported as
`\pdfcolorstack 0 pop` with pdf(La)TeX, or as `\special{color pop}` with
(La)TeX. In any case, this node inhibits the effect of `\unskip` exactly as
a `\write` node does.

As a matter of fact, if the `lua-visual-debug` package were *not* loaded,
this node containing the instruction for restoring colors would *not* be
appended after the last line of the caption in the first of the OP’s
examples, because the caption, in itself, does not make use of color.
Indeed, consider the following variation of the code presented above:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{color}

% \setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{\bigskipamount}

% \makeatletter
% 
% \def\endminipage{%
%     \par
% %     \unskip
%     \ifvoid\@mpfootins\else
%       \vskip\skip\@mpfootins
%       \normalcolor
%       \footnoterule
%       \unvbox\@mpfootins
%     \fi
%     \@minipagefalse   %% added 24 May 89
%   \color@endgroup
%   \egroup
%   \expandafter\@iiiparbox\@mpargs{\unvbox\@tempboxa}}
% 
% \makeatother

\showboxbreadth = 1000
\showboxdepth = 10
% \tracingoutput = 1



\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.6\linewidth}
    \centering
    \rule{0.99\linewidth}{60pt}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.4\linewidth}
    \caption{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.6\linewidth}
    \centering
    \rule{0.99\linewidth}{60pt}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.4\linewidth}
    \caption{\color{red}The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.6\linewidth}
    \centering
    \rule{0.99\linewidth}{60pt}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.4\linewidth}
    \caption{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}
    \label{fig:fox}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

% \showlists

\setbox0 = \vbox{
    \hsize = 10cm
    \prevdepth = 2pt % not actually important
    The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.\par
    \label{box}
}

The depth of \verb|\box0| is \the\dp0.

% \showbox0

\unvbox0

\end{document}
```

If you compile it, you will notice that the descenders of the caption of
the first figure, that neither uses color nor is followed by a `\label`
command, do extend below the baseline, while those of the other two
captions don’t; in the case of the second figure, this is due to the
presence of color inside the caption itself (uncomment `\showlists` and see
the transcript file for the full details).  However, the `lua-visual-debug`
package includes (when loaded together with `color`) some colored lines
inside the box of the caption, thus, in that case, the first example
behaves like the second one (since color *is* equally present inside that
box).

Answer (score 3):

In the first case, the last item in the caption minipage is the second line of the caption. In the second case, the last item is the whatsit TeX places for later transforming it in the `\write` instruction to the auxiliary file.

This item has no depth, so the reference point of the last item in the second case is at the bottom of the minipage. In the first case, the reference point is at the baseline of the caption's second line.

Solution: use

```
\caption{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.\label{fig:fox}}
```

Now the whatsit belongs to the paragraph and so the reference point is computed like in the first example.

Comment: Please forgive my punctiliuosness, by I’m actually interested in the fine details and I would be grateful if you could provide more insight (I know you can! :-) : according to the rules given on pages 80 (bottom)/81 (top), a “whatsit” should *not* have this effect, only glue following the last box in a `\vbox` should; and indeed, `\tracingoutput` shows that, in the second figure, a `\glue 0.0` comes after the last line of the caption and before the `\write`.  Can you trace down where this glue comes from?  (Only if you already know the answer, I’m not asking to debug the LaTeX kernel for me!).

Comment: I already tried that and at first it seemed to solve the problem. But after adding the `color` package, the alignment was off again; this time even if no `\label` follows the `\caption` command.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti Pass. ;-)

Comment: @Johannes The joys of color in LaTeX!

Comment: And I've always been told that the world is not black and white... `:)`

Comment: I think I have found it: it is the `\@makecaption` command that *always* adds `\vskip\belowcaptionskip` after a caption (`classes.pdf`, l. 1122); but a `minipage` issues `\unskip` at the end, thus removing it.  But if the `\unskip` finds a whatsit (be it a `\write` or, as in the case of colors, a `\special`)...