# Space after figure changes when enclosed in additional minipage

Tags: spacing, minipage

Can someone tell me what the origin of this behavior is.

I have the following MVE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    head=20mm,
    left=20mm,
    right=10mm,
    top=25mm,
    bottom=25mm,
    foot=8mm
}
\usepackage[default,scale=0.95]{opensans} %Schriftart FEHLER

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{setspace}   
\usepackage{floatflt,epsfig} 
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
\setlength{\fboxrule}{1pt}%
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{7pt}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{7pt}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{10pt}

\linespread{1.0}   
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}                 % verhindert Absatzeinrueckung nach Bildern

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

% CAPTION STYLE
\DeclareCaptionFormat{labelstyle}{% <- needed
\setlength\fboxsep{3pt}% <- needed
\colorbox{blue}{{#1}}#2#3%
} 
\definecolor{blue}{HTML}{336699}
\captionsetup[table]{singlelinecheck=false, labelfont={color=white}}    % Rechtsbündige Tabellen und Bildbeschreibung
\captionsetup[figure]{format=labelstyle, labelfont={color=white}, 
justification=raggedright,% <- only needed if longer captions should not be justified
singlelinecheck=false% <- added
}

\newcommand{\midpict}[4]{%
\begin{center}
    \begin{minipage}{#2\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{#1}
        \captionof{figure}{#3}\label{#4}
    \end{minipage}
\end{center}%
}
\newmdenv[nobreak=true,backgroundcolor=white!20,linecolor=black,skipabove=10,skipbelow=10]{whitebox}

\begin{document}
%\input{./doc-config.tex}


\begin{minipage}{\textwidth} %<--- It's about this one
    \blindtext
    \midpict{./content/figures/placeholder.png}{0.5}{Caption}{fig:A}
\end{minipage}
\blindtext
\midpict{./content/figures/placeholder.png}{0.5}{Caption2}{fig:A}
\blindtext % <- Here the skip is as expected
\end{document}
```

Often I pair an image with some explanatory text and if I don't want Latex to include a pagebreak between my image and my text I enclose the two in an additional `minipage` environment. But this changes the space after the image to the next following element. Why does this additional `minipage` make a difference and what parameter do I have to manipulate to have the same spacing between image and following text/another image as if there wouldn't be another `minipage`?

Comment: Your example has some dependencies, namely `./doc-config.tex` and `./content/figures/placeholder.png`.

Comment: you haven't provided any usable test file to show the effect or test answers but I could make a guess.  the space from `\end{center}` and the caption will be combined if they are at the same level, but the extra box will prevent `\end{center}` seeing the caption so you will get the full space from both constructs.

Comment: sorry, `doc-config.tex` isn't needed and can be removed. the `placeholder.png` is just a random image - can I replace it with something?

Comment: David, with the extra box I get less space than without it, or did I misunderstand your comment?

Comment: @po.pe  Run `texdoc mwe`

Comment: Where should I run it?

Comment: @po.pr In the command prompt  (that odd black window with c:\> )

Comment: Tells me `documentation for mwe could not be found` :)

Comment: Possibly related: [Exact alignment of caption beside figure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/298713); it may, or may not, be the same problem.  Please make your example compilable.

Comment: It should be compilable beside the missing image, what should I use instead? I'm not sure if my problem is the same as in the linked answer, because I do have `\label` and wouldn't already the inner `minipage` then cause the skip of `\belowcaptionskip`?

Comment: I would in general be interested in understanding how one would debug such a problem? Can you somehow see what's going on in the background? For me it's sometimes not really obvious what Latex is doing, I'd expect nesting multiple `minipages` shouldn't have any negative impact.

Comment: If more information is needed just let me know and I'll try to provide it, this drives me crazy :)